# Node visulaization in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

How we can change Property name/Values manually in Neo4j. Which Property should be in centre to show relationships with other nodes.
[An example just to elaborate the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvTeR.jpg)

In graph output,How "Tom Hanks" can be replaced with some other property of Tom Hanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the visualizer running in the browser view, and not neo4j itself.

If you check the node labels at the top of the output view, tap on the label related to the thing you want to change (it may also show if you tap on the node in question to give it focus). Now, at the bottom of the window, you should see properties of that node. Tap on the one that you want to show up for nodes of that label in the visualizer.

Comment: What is difference between "Visualizer running in browser and Neo4j".My understanding is  Visualizer is part of Neo4j or Is there any Client version of Neo4j available?. I am using Community version.                                Now to the question.................                                                         When I tap on label, I could see Properties at the bottom, but it doesn't allow me to tap further.

Comment: Now, I can change the Node Visualization with the same option as you mentioned. Thanks